# SMLNJ - Typcon mismatch with declared types

Tags: types, sml, lex

I have the following issue: I am working through A. Appel's compiler in ML and I have written the following simple structure

```
signature Tiger_Tokens = 
sig
    type linenum;
    type token;
    val ADD : linenum*linenum -> token;
    val INT : string*linenum*linenum -> token;
    val EOF : linenum*linenum -> token;
end

structure Tokens :> Tiger_Tokens =
    struct
        type linenum = int;
        type token = string

        fun ADD(i,j) = "ADD"
        fun INT(number, i, j) = "INT"
        fun EOF(i,j) = "EOF"
    end
```

Using ML-lex library I am compiling this with

```
type lexresult = Tokens.token
val lineNum = ref 1;
fun eof() = Tokens.EOF(!lineNum, !lineNum)

%%
digits=[0-9];
%%
\n => (!lineNum = (!lineNum) + 1; lex());
"+" => (Tokens.ADD(yypos,yypos+1));
{digits}+ => (Tokens.INT(yytext, yypos,yypos+1));
```

and I get the following error

```
tiger.lex.sml:172.8-172.33 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: Tokens.linenum * Tokens.linenum
  operand:         int * int
  in expression:
    Tokens.ADD (yypos,yypos + 1)
```

Now clearly I have set the type linenum to be an int. But when I call a function that expects a type linenum (which is int), and I pass an int as an argument (yypos), then it asks for Token.linenum not int. Isnt this an int since I set it as such? Or does SML see these as different types. If they do see them as different types then what is the point of a type declaration other than naming a 'special' kind of int??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was the signature ascription you have, i.e., the `:>` part in:

```
structure Tokens :> Tiger_Tokens =
```

What this does is effectively hide all types in `Tokens`. It's called an *opaque* signature ascription.

There's another form that will actually expose all the types: a *transparent* signature ascription:

```
structure Tokens : Tiger_Tokens =
```

The middle ground is called a *translucent* signature ascription and would look like this:

```
structure Tokens :> Tiger_Tokens where type linenum = int =
```

This exposes just the `linenum` type, while `token` remains abstract.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution I am implementing is to declare the type in the signature. In other words

```
signature Tiger_Tokens = 
sig
    type linenum = int;
    type token;
    val ADD : linenum*linenum -> token;
    val INT : string*linenum*linenum -> token;
    val EOF : linenum*linenum -> token;
end
```

But then you still need a bit of redundency and you still have to redeclare it in your structure. Hope this helps someone!